# Get new dll path that has been renamed during process running

Tags: c++, windows, dll, process

On windows, during process running, I manually rename a dll that process loaded. How process can get new dll path from it's old path?

Comment: You could enumerate modules to find a handle for the old path. This is the base address of the mapped DLL, so you can get the native NT path via [`GetMappedFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683195).

Comment: Internally, this calls [`NtQueryVirtualMemory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvirtualmemory) for the  `MemoryMappedFilenameInformation`, which calls [`ObQueryNameString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-obquerynamestring) on the  mapped File. This calls the `QueryNameProcedure` for the File type, which queries the device name and requests the `FileNameInformation` from the filesystem and concatenates them as the full path -- e.g. "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\path\to\renamed.dll".

Comment: So, we scan memory or peb to get mapped dll handle, then use it to find the new path. Is it the way you are talking about?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For getting the module handle, you can call `EnumProcessModulesEx` to get the list of module handles and then `GetModuleFileNameEx` to read the fully-qualified name as loaded from the process loader data. Then once the target path is found, call `GetMappedFileName` on the module handle (i.e. module base address) to get the current filename of the mapped DLL.

Comment: Thank for your help @eryksun